# Properly hardcode Javascript variables into HTML

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I realize my title isn't perfectly clear, but I couldn't come up with a better one. So here goes:

I work on an e-commerce website where different products should have different maximum order ammounts. Since writing plugins for the CMS is not really an option, I want to solve this with javascript.

What I want to do:

> 1. Check wether a div with the class "order-limit" exists
> 2. Read that divs data-limit-attribute, which contains a number
> 3. Add a sentence including the number

Now today I read http://danwebb.net/2010/1/27/put-that-data-attribute-away-son-you-might-hurt-someone which basically said:

> Don't use data-* attributes for javascript.

So now I wonder: What's the best practice to do what I did, given that products have different upper limits?

Comment: What he's saying is you shouldn't use data attributes when HTML or Javascript already provide features to do what you want (like `href` and hidden fields). It should be used when the data is semantically relevant to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this quote from the article you've linked is self-explanatory enough:

> By all means, use data-* attributes to add semantically valuable data
>   to your HTML but if you are just using it to prop up a script you are
>   writing think again.

By the way, I don't believe there's a BEST way, only the best way for your specific situation and needs.